# how to match a character variable with a regex defined in another variable?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Consider this simple example

```
import pandas as pd

mydata = pd.DataFrame({'mystring' : ['heLLohelloy1', 'hAllohallo'],
                       'myregex' : ['hello.[0-9]', 'ulla']})

mydata
Out[3]: 
       myregex      mystring
0  hello.[0-9]  heLLohelloy1
1         ulla    hAllohallo
```

I would like to create a variable `flag` that identifies the rows where `mystring` matches with the regex in `myregex` for the same row.

That is, in the example, only the first row `heLLohelloy1` matches with the regex `hello.[0-9]`. Indeed, `hAllohallo` does not match with the regex `ulla`.

How can I do that as efficiently as possible in Pandas? Here we are talking about millions of observations (still the data fits into the RAM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re library` and `apply function` do the following:

```
import re

# apply function
mydata['flag'] = mydata.apply(lambda row: bool(re.search(row['myregex'], row['mystring'])), axis=1)

### to convert bool to int - optional
### mydata['flag'] = mydata['flag'].astype(int)

       myregex      mystring    flag
0   hello.[0-9] heLLohelloy1    True
1   ulla        hAllohallo      False
```

Comment: sweet. i wonder which regex package would be faster here. is `re` the bestest ? :)

Comment: I don't know about being best but `re` is surely the most widely used and well developed python library to solve regex problems.

Answer (score 1):

I come up with this solution , can you check on your side whether meet your requirement

```
[pd.Series(y).str.contains(x)[0] for x,y in zip(mydata.myregex,mydata.mystring)]

Out[54]: [True, False]
```

Or we using `map`

```
list(map(lambda x: pd.Series(x[1]).str.contains(x[0])[0], zip(mydata.myregex,mydata.mystring)))
Out[56]: [True, False]
```

Comment: thanks Wen, but how can you create the `flag` variable (True, False) in the dataframe based on that?

Comment: `df['flag']=list(map(lambda x: pd.Series(x[1]).str.contains(x[0])[0], zip(mydata.myregex,mydata.mystring)))` assign it back maybe ? @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ